# YTPlayer View not working properly in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, ytplayerview

I am using `YTPlayerView` in the application to play YouTube videos. It is working proper in `iPad` but not in `iPhone`. In `iPhone` the player directly plays in full screen due to which any gesture on the player is not working. Have to exit full screen using the full screen button on the controls for any gesture to be recognised.

Can the controls of the player be hidden. Tried using `@"controls" : @"0"` works fine in `iPad` but not in `iPhone`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit. Hope this will solve your problem.